# XY Tools unavailable under QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I cannot find XY tools plugin in QGIS repository.

Answer (score 7):

XY Tools is deprecated for QGIS 3.x.

You can use [Spreadsheetlayers Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/) to import `*.ods`, `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` files or the core plugin `Add Delimited Text` via `Layer --> Add Layer --> Add Delimited Text Layer` to import `.csv` files instead.

Export Layer as Excel-File or CSV is also a core function of QGIS 3. You can do this by `right-clicking the layer` you wish to export and choosing `export --> save as... --> format --> ...`

Comment: Thanks. I used the export layer as an excel file and it worked the way I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin is not available under QGIS 3.

1. Click on this link (the official deposit of this plugin :https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/
2. Click on the github link : https://github.com/rduivenvoorde/xytools
3. Consult the file metadata.txt: the maximum version of QGIS is 2.99 :https://github.com/rduivenvoorde/xytools/blob/master/metadata.txt

You can directly click on the last link if you want.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this plugin was not converted to v3, so it can't be installed.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/